# How to "select" a "cell" within a vector based on the value of another vector in that case/row

Tags: r, database

I have a very specific thing I'm trying to do, but I'm hoping to generalize to something that might be a little more useful in the future.

I'm also self taught, so please bear with me. I know this is a simple function, I just don't have the right language to google it.

Say I have a dataframe:

```
user = c("Bob", "Jane", "Alice") 
income = c(40000, 50000, 42000) 
rent = c(1000, 1800, 900)
groceries = c(400, 250, 600)

df = data.frame(user, income, rent, groceries)
```

| user | income | rent | groceries |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 40000 | 1000 | 400 |
| Jane | 50000 | 1800 | 250 |
| Alice | 42000 | 900 | 600 |

Say, for whatever reason, I wanted to divide everyone's rent by Bob's income. Currently, I'm using min() and max() functions,  but this is susceptible to error -- i.e., I have 10,000 cases and Bob's income isn't actually the smallest. So I'm looking for a way to say:

```
 df$rent_per_income = df$rent / df$income** WHEN **df$user == "Bob"
```

Essentially I'm looking for a way to select a specific cell/data point, and the criteria is based another value in that row ( I don't want to transpose the data so I can use an if then argument).

I know how to select a cell based on it's position, but again, that seems really vulnerable to my Amelia Bedelia buffoonery  Another thought I had was to save Bob's income as a value, then divide by value, but I KNOW there's a better way to do it.

```
df1 = df %>%
   filter(user == "Bob")
x = df1$income
rm(df1)

df$rent_per_income = df$rent / x

rm(x)
```

My expected outcome would be:

| user | income | rent | groceries | rent_per_income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 40000 | 1000 | 400 | 0.025 |
| Jane | 50000 | 1800 | 250 | 0.045 |
| Alice | 42000 | 900 | 600 | 0.0225 |

Comment: `df$rent_per_income = df$rent / df$income[df$user == "Bob"]` or `df %>% mutate(rent_per_income = rent / income[user == "Bob"])`

Comment: @JonSpring

Square Brackets!!! Thank you - I knew it was such a basic function but I wasn't even googling the right terms. The first solution worked. The second one would also work, but I have a government computer and a dataset that is 2 WHOLE gb, and adding a bunch of variables might actually make it explode

Comment: The output of the two variations would be the same, adding a `rent_per_income` variable to the `df` data frame, based on the `rent` and `income` columns of `df`.

Answer (score 0):

It often pays to be explicit and work in self documenting steps; especially if one fears 'amela bedelia bufoonery'
consider

```
df = data.frame(user = c("Bob", "Jane", "Alice"), 
                income = c(40000, 50000, 42000), 
                rent = c(1000, 1800, 900),
                groceries = c(400, 250, 600))
library(dplyr)
mutate(df,
       bobs_income = max(income * (user=="Bob"),na.rm = TRUE),
       rent_divided_by_bobs_income = rent/bobs_income)
```

```
   user income rent groceries bobs_income rent_divided_by_bobs_income
1   Bob  40000 1000       400       40000                      0.0250
2  Jane  50000 1800       250       40000                      0.0450
3 Alice  42000  900       600       40000                      0.0225
```

Comment: This is a good approach, especially if there's ever a chance that there might be more or less than one row with the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

From Jon Spring

It's square brackets if anyone else is looking

```
df$rent_per_income = df$rent / df$income[df$user == "Bob"]
```